# These commands (setxkbmap and xcape) are in .profile but are not being executed on login

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys, xorg, .profile, xkb

I have verified that .profile is executed on login.

However, commands involving setxkbap (e.g. `setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps`) and xcape (e.g. `xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'`) seem to be ignored.

Since both programs are for keyboard bindings I figured the reasons they are ignored is related. How can I get them to run on login?

Using Ubuntu 22.04 on Xorg (xcape doesn't work on Wayland).

Comment: Probably better to use Tweaks (you may need to install `gnome-tweaks`) to change the keyboard behavior in this respect.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Unfortunately it is impossible to replicate the behaviour of xcape with gnome-tweaks.

Comment: Maybe that particular combo is not so easy... Another thought is to put those commands in a shell script and [autostart](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html) that script at login.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I managed to do it by using startup applications, but I had to run them as a script with a delay of a few seconds (`sleep 10`). If you want to put this in an answer I will mark it as solved to help others. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Please feel free to use it in an own answer. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This can done with [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en).

Put your commands in a file with a delay command at the top (this is because keyboard bindings need the desktop environment to be loaded before they can be executed):

```
sleep 10;
setxkbmap ...;
xcape ...;
```

Save this as `keybinds.sh` then in Startup Applications click Add and in the popup dialogue, add this in the Command field (just change the location of keybinds script).

```
/bin/bash -c "sh /home/user/.../keybinds.sh"
```

When you login, after 10 seconds the script will run.