# setxkbmap randomly stops working

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have the following in my `~/.profile`:

`setxkbmap us,no -option "grp:shift_caps_toggle" -option "caps:escape"`

and I am running i3 https://i3wm.org/ under Ubuntu 20.04. I am using shift+caps to toggle keyboard layouts between "us" and "no", and I have replaced my caps lock with escape.

This randomly stops working and I have to run the `setxkbmap ...` command again in a terminal.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: This question: [These commands (setxkbmap and xcape) are in .profile but are not being executed on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470596/these-commands-setxkbmap-and-xcape-are-in-profile-but-are-not-being-executed) may be helpful in that case.

Comment: Similar, but I'm certain that the command is executed and that it does indeed work as intended on login. However, after some time it stops working. I'm assuming that some sort of ubuntu software overwrites my setxkbmap settings somehow, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Note the `sleep` command in that answer. (But don't put `sleep` into `~/.profile`.)